# Build fails in Release mode but works fine in Debug - Entity Framework 6.0 related issue

Tags: entity-framework, build, compiler-errors, release

I build my application and run it in debug mode. Everything is ok. I can test the functionality and everything is working. Its a multi tier MVC application using Entity Framework 6.0.

Now, when I change the build from Debug to Release and build the projects. I get a few hundreds build errors. All the errors are in the Data Access layer where I use the Entity Framework 6.0. The errors are in the form of:

Error   388 The type or namespace name 'DbSet' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Or

Error   201 The type or namespace name 'Schema' does not exist in the namespace 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I have tried cleaning the solution and rebuilding but always same. Not sure why this can happen? Any suggestion will be appreciated.

many thanks